# Image to byte array

Tags: java, image, image-processing

When an Image (e.g.,jpg) is converted to byte array, how the byte array is encoded with new line? or how the length and width of the image is represented in the array of bytes.

Comment: None of the above? Bytes are bytes - a file isn't "converted" into a byte array; you're simply reading the bytes from the file into an array in memory.

Comment: ... and that byte[] itself has no knowledge what kind of image this is, how tall or how wide it is (or that it even is an image). For that, you need to pass the bytes on to an image processing library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image metadata are described by the respective image format specification and stored in the same image file, so you need to examine the respective spec to find out how to determine the image dimensions in that format.

[This page](http://www.anttikupila.com/flash/getting-jpg-dimensions-with-as3-without-loading-the-entire-file/) goes into detail about how to determine a JPEG image dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

This depends largely on the format used to encode the image - different image formats encode the image data in very different ways.

Fortunately, you should never really need to care - such conversion is taken care of by libraries in most cases. e.g. for Java if you want to read a write a .jpg file then you should just use the [ImageIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/package-summary.html) package and not worry about the specific representation.